# How did Dr. Niven constructed the polynomial in his proof that $\pi$ was irrational

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation, irrational-numbers, pi

Recently I am trying to understand Dr. Niven's [proof](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183510788#ui-tabs-1) that $\pi$ is an irrational number.

In the beginning of his proof, he constructed a polynomial -- $f(x) = \frac{x^{n}(a - bx)^{n}}{n!}$.

So I wondered that why did he constructed it this way?

Comment: Please make your question more self-contained. At the very least include an exact reference.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.1929 and references therein might give you some intuition.

Comment: The original approach is by Hermit for proof of transcendence of $e$. The key idea is to find polynomial whose derivatives (upto a certain order) vanish at $0$ and $\pi$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supposing $\pi$ is rational, then there exist integers $a,b$ such that $\pi = \frac {a}{b}$

$f(x) = \frac {x^n(a-bx)^n}{n!}$

This polynomial was chosen such that the following would be true.

$f(0) = 0$ and $f(\frac {a}{b}) = 0$

As we take derivatives,

$f'(x) = \frac {nx^{n-1}(a-bx)^n - nbx^n(a-bx)^{n-1}}{n!}\\
f''(x) = \frac {n(n-1)x^{n-2}(a-bx)^n - 2nbx^{n-1}(a-bx)^{n-1} + n(n-1)b^2x^n(a-bx)^{n-2}}{n!}$

Etc.

And we evaluate at $0, \frac {a}{b}$

$f^{(j)}(0) = 0, f^{(j)}(\frac {a}{b}) = 0$ if $j< n$ and $f^{(j)}(0), f^{(j)}(\frac {a}{b})$ will be an integer in all cases.

Next thing that is important about this function:

$0< x^n < (\frac ab)^n$ for all $x$ in $(0,\frac {a}{b}),$ and
$0< (a-bx)^n < a^n$ for all $x$ in $(0,\frac {a}{b}).$

$0<f(x) <\frac {\pi^n a^n}{n!}$ in the interval $(0,\pi)$